# Entity Framework query - Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This project is coded in c# with ASP.NET MVC.

Hello, I created database with Entity Framework and add some data. Now I want to fetch that data and put it inside variable.

This is how I  fetch data and it worked:

```
string hash = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select PasswordHash From Users where Username = 'Paul'").FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

When I want to put variable into query like that:

```
    string hash = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select PasswordHash From Users where Username = @username").FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

It is not working and the error message says that:

> 'Must declare the scalar variable "@username".'

Is there any way to fetch data with variable inside query with entity framework?

I read how to do it with standard sql connection by adding parameteres like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you read the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way, create sql parameter and attach that to query like

```
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter> {
    new SqlParameter("@username", username) 
};
string query = "Select PasswordHash From Users where Username = @username";

string hash = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query, parameters.ToArray()).FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `SqlQuery` has another overload that allows you to pass your data into the query.

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx)

Example (from msdn):

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogId = 1; 

    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("dbo.GetBlogById @p0", blogId).Single(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Database thinks that @username is a variable thats why you get that error message. You can, what you said, use parameters and that would replace the parameter with its value. The parameters are passed to that very method you are using as an array.